# Conver a list of tuple to list, modify it , then convert it back

Tags: python

I want to write a function, where I want to remove overlapping intervals from the second parameter.
The parameters (list of tuple) are integer intervals, for example:[(8, 23)]. End if its overlaps with first parameter, remove the overlapping interval from it. For example:
If the first parameter is [(0, 10)] and the second is [(8, 23)], I want change the second parameter to [(11, 23)].
I tried like this:

```
def remove_overlapping_products(brand_positions, product_positions):
brand_pos_list = list(brand_positions)
product_pos_list = list(product_positions)

    
def check_overlap(brand_pos_list, product_pos_list):
    if product_pos_list[0]>= brand_pos_list[0] and product_pos_list[0]<= brand_pos_list[1]:
        product_pos_list[0] =  brand_pos_list[1]-1
        return True
    if product_pos_list[1]>= brand_pos_list[0] and product_pos_list[1]<= brand_pos_list[1]:
        product_pos_list[1] =  brand_pos_list[0]-1
        return True

   

for x in brand_pos_list:
    for y in product_pos_list:
        check_overlap(x, y)
         

                            
product_positions_new = tuple(product_pos_list)                
            
return [pos for pos in product_positions_new]
```

But I got the error message:
"'tuple' object does not support item assignment". Since I used a converted list, I can't understand the reason of this message.

Can someone help me with my code?

Comment: Are you under the impression that, e.g. `list(brand_positions)` will create a list *of lists* from the list of tuples? Why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to ask a [more specific question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: When I run your code using `remove_overlapping_products([(0, 10)], [(11, 23)])` I don't get any errors. Is that not how I'm suppose to use `remove_overlapping_products`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the second parameter only, it can be a shorter solution:

```
def check_overlap(x,y):
    return True if x[1]>=y[0] else False
     
def remove_overlap(brand_positions, product_positions):
    return [(x[1]+1, y[1]) if (check_overlap(x, y) and x[1]<y[1]) else y for (x, y) in zip(brand_positions, product_positions)]
```

Example:

```
X = [(0,10), (2,5), (6,9)]
Y = [(8,23), (5,7), (1,7)]

print(remove_overlap(X,Y))
```

Output:

```
[(11, 23), (6, 7), (1, 7)]
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really help me a lot.